# Set value to textfield with hooks and redux material ui

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-hooks, redux-saga

I'm building an app using react, redux, and redux-saga.
The situation is that I'm getting information from an API. In this case, I'm getting the information about a movie, and I will update this information using a basic form.
What I would like to have in my text fields is the value from the object of the movie that I'm calling form the DB.
This is a brief part of my code:
Im using 'name' as an example.
Parent component:

```
 const MovieForm = (props) => {
  const {
    movie,
  } = props;

  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    onSubmit({
      name,
    });
  };

  const handleSetValues = () => {
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(movie, name);
    setName(movie.name);
    setValues(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (movie && values === false) {
      handleSetValues();
    }
  });

  return (
    <Container>
      <TextField
        required
        **defaultValue={() => {
          console.log(movie, name);
          return movie ? movie.name : name;
        }}**
        label='Movie Title'
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default MovieForm;
    ....
```

child component

```
const MovieUpdate = (props) => {
  const { history } = props;
  const { id } = props.match.params;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const loading = useSelector((state) => _.get(state, 'MovieUpdate.loading'));
  const created = useSelector((state) => _.get(state, 'MovieUpdate.created'));
  const loadingFetch = useSelector((state) =>
    _.get(state, 'MovieById.loading')
  );
  const movie = useSelector((state) => _.get(state, 'MovieById.results'));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading === false && created === true) {
      dispatch({
        type: MOVIE_UPDATE_RESET,
      });
    }
    if (loadingFetch === false && movie === null) {
      dispatch({
        type: MOVIE_GET_BY_ID_STARTED,
        payload: id,
      });
    }
  });

  const updateMovie = (_movie) => {
    const _id = id;
    const obj = {
      id: _id,
      name: _movie.name,
    }
    console.log(obj);
    dispatch({
      type: MOVIE_UPDATE_STARTED,
      payload: obj,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MovieForm
        title='Update a movie'
        buttonTitle='update'
        movie={movie}
        onCancel={() => history.push('/app/movies/list')}
        onSubmit={updateMovie}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieUpdate;
```

Then, the actual problem is that when I use the default prop on the text field the information appears without any problem, but if i use `defaultValue` it is empty.

Comment: it's not entirely clear to me what the problem is. are you talking about this line? `defaultValue={movie ? movie.name : name}`

Comment: Yes, that one, the problem is that after i get the values from the request, i want to display them into the texffields. But it just happens when i use the prop 'value' which does not allow to edit, if i use the 'defaultValue' i just get a empty box

Comment: can you `console.log(movie, name) ` what does that show?

Comment: If I do it from the line using an arrow function, it doesn't even execute the consolo.log. But doing it from handleSetValues I got the JSON of the object

Comment: can you edit your code above to show a console.log statement and it's output please

Comment: Sure, give me me a sec

Comment: I think is ready, or did you mean to create a snippet ?

Comment: you have console.log but you haven't told me what is being output

Comment: I just got an answer from the handler, which is the complete object with its values, i would love to share a pic from it, but i cant

Comment: hi from handler
MovieForm.jsx:83 
{id: "8c48c2f9-95da-4303-9cc9-3ef3cf227cd6", name: "dd", description: "d", genre: "d", duration: "d", …}
description: "d"
duration: "d"
genre: "d"
id: "8c48c2f9-95da-4303-9cc9-3ef3cf227cd6"
imageUrl: "d"
movieUrl: "d"
name: "dd"
uploadedAt: "2020-06-13T19:19:07.000Z"
year: "d"

Comment: can you show the `TextField` component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215933/discussion-between-leon-diego-and-red-baron).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I kind of got the answer, I read somewhere that the defaultValue can't be used int the rendering.
So I cheat in a way, I set the properties multiline and row={1} (according material-ui documentation) and I was able to edit this field an receive a value to display it in the textfield